# How to get Prettier to keep ending symbol of ending tag on the same line

Tags: prettier

For some reason, when I use an emmet abbreviation like this:
 div>button.round-button+button>i.fas.fa-icons

and I save the file to trigger the Prettier formatter, it will format it like this:

```html
<div>
    <button class="round-button"></button
    ><button><i class="fas fa-icons"></i></button>
</div>
```

But, on the third line, I don't want the line to start with the end of the first button tag

I've done a quick look through settings but I didn't find anything relating to this. Is there a setting I can change or would it be best to give feedback to Prettier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding whitespace between the `button` tags is unsafe. It affects the output in the browser. Either add this whitespace manually if you need it or use [the `htmlWhitespaceSensitivity` option](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity) if you don't care about the safety of the formatting.